# Can you create a session variable without a value?

Tags: php, forms, session

My question is simply as asked in the title.

Upon login I'd like to create a token that looks like this:

```
 $_SESSION['token'] === true
```

Another page in my directory consists of an if statement that looks like this:

```
   if($_SESSION['token'] === false)
    {die('not logged in');}
```

However, even when logged in, the page dies instead of displaying appropriate `HTML` that would display if the token was true.

Comment: Learn about the difference between comparison and assignment.

Comment: What errors you getting? Why are you using === instead of = to assign true?

Comment: Your title is cryptic. Why do you consider `$_SESSION['token']` to be a session variable "without a value"? You look like you want to store a value in it.

Comment: Because I have other session variables that appear when I use var_dump however for some reason $_session['token'] does not appear Or get passed to the other page. So I cannot use it to verify the user has been logged in - since it is not being stored for some reason. I thought the reason was because it had no assigned value

Comment: create a `session` object in a separate file and then `require` it in both files

Comment: Can I use !isset instead of comparing it to false?

Answer (score 0):

As another user has alluded to in the comments. You are not attempting to create a session variable with the following line:

```
$_SESSION['token'] === true;
```

This is not an assignment.  If you wanted to assign a value you'd need to do something like the following:

```
$_SESSION['token'] = true;
```

I've guessing you might have solved this issue by now but for some reason I like to dredge through unanswered questions.

Of course, you can compare the session variable just like any other variable once it is set. However, unless you set the value to false it won't match a test for false. You could certainly use isset() once you assign a value to it.